# Call method in page_load cause StackOverflowException on adapter.fill() but no problem called elsewhere

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am so confused right now.
I have multiple methods that binds gridview from sql connection.

When I call those from a dropdown index change, it runs fine.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int machineid = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
  try { 
  connection.Open();
  EquimentBind(machineid);
      
  }
 
  finally { connection.Close(); }

}
```

But when I call the methods from page_load and pass the id from URL it always give me StackOverflowException on the adapter.fill(dataTable) step.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  

  if (!IsPostBack)
      {
    string station_id = Request.QueryString["station_id"];
   

    if (station_id != null)
        {
         
      DropDownList1.Visible = false;
      int machineid = int.Parse(station_id);
      try
      {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
          connection.Open();
        }
        EquimentBind(machineid);
       
      }

      finally { connection.Close(); }
    }   
        else
        {
         
          try
            {
              if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) { connection.Open(); }
              SqlDataAdapter adapter = //My sql command
              DataTable stalist = new DataTable();
              adapter.Fill(stalist);
              DropDownList1.DataSource = stalist;
              DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
              DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
              DropDownList1.DataBind();

            }

            finally { connection.Close(); }
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString('0');

      
        }
        
       

      }
```

Below is my data binding method:

```
 protected void EquimentBind(int machineid)
{
  

 
  SqlCommand Sqlcommand = // my sql command
  SqlCommand command = Sqlcommand;
  SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
  DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
  sd.Fill(dt1);
  GV_Equipments.DataSource = dt1;
  GV_Equipments.DataBind();
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  dt1.Clear();
 

}
```

The StackOverflowExecption always throw at sd.Fill(dt1) row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: You have an anti-pattern here that I call try/squelch. That happens when you use a try block but the catch is empty or missing. This means that critical information about errors encountered are lost which makes debugging nearly impossible.

Comment: Thank you @Sean, the only reason I use try is to finally close the connection no matter what. Which is another problem I have: the connection always states open at page load, I had to use a condition to open connection. But something is off here.

Comment: I figured it out. one of my gridview has ondatabinding=page load. causing the infinite loop.

Comment: Instead of using finally to close your connections you should wrap your connections (and anything else implementing iDisposable) in a using statement. That way it will always properly handle disposing of you objects as soon as you finish with them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using

Answer (score 0):

The StackOverflowException is likely occurring because the EquimentBind method is being recursively called in an infinite loop. This can happen when the Page_Load event is triggered repeatedly due to the postback caused by the data binding process.

Remove the data binding logic from the Page_Load event when station_id is null, as it is unnecessary and causing the recursive calls. You can simplify the Page_Load event as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string station_id = Request.QueryString["station_id"];

        if (station_id != null)
        {
            DropDownList1.Visible = false;
            int machineid = int.Parse(station_id);
            try
            {
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                EquimentBind(machineid);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = //My sql command
                DataTable stalist = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(stalist);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = stalist;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

Modify the DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged event to handle both cases, i.e., when the selection is changed from the dropdown and when it is loaded from the URL:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int machineid = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        EquimentBind(machineid);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed data binding and called index changing in page load but still the same issue